# Javascript: code refactoring to single line instead of multiple line for loop

Tags: javascript

I am new to react and javascript , trying to refactor my below code to fewer lines:

```
for (const email of processedData) {
     if (validateEmail(email)) {
          count++;
          if (count === 100) {
             break;
           }
      }
 }
```

processedData is a list of emails, tried using reduce but in reduce i could not break once i have count === 100

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will run a function on your array's element until that function returns true.

Then you can do something like this :

**EDIT** : single line version of my first suggestion.

```js
var processedData = ["joe@test.co.uk", "john@test.co.uk", "jack@test.com", "jane@test.com", "amy@test.com"];
var count = 0;

processedData.some(email => validateEmail(email) && (++count === 2));
 
function validateEmail(email) {
  console.log("validateEmail " + email);
  return (email.indexOf(".com") > -1);
}
```

Comment: @dikash I accepted your edit but added a return to the validateEmail function. Because your suggestion now makes the code dependant on the value returned by the validateEmail function.

Comment: validateEmail function returns true if email is valid, you got it right

Comment: And you want it to loop until 100 emails are valid, right?

Answer (score 4):

At least the loop body can be compressed easily:

```
for(const email of processedData) {
    if(validateEmail(email) && ++count === 100) break
}
```

It would be hard to make it even shorter. >_>

Comment: `for(const email of processedData) if(validateEmail(email) && ++count === 100) break;`

Comment: doesn't map or reduce contain break statements, i was thinking on that line, because map, filter, reduce look more elegant, the answer is good though i can use it

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay then won't it be `validateEmail() && ++count==100 && break`?

Comment: @Zenoo I've split the body from `for` to make it fit into the page. <_<

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just want to have an array with 100 items, then this could help. Apply .filter() on the data array and then slice it to 100.

```
processedData.filter(email => validateEmail(email)).slice(0,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think... it shoud help, but probably is better way to refactor (as always)

```
for(const email of processedData){
  if(validateEmail(email) && count != 100) count++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using below loop?

```
for(let i=0,count=0; i < processedData.length && count<100; i++){
    count+=validateEmail(processedData[i])
}
```

Comment: Or event more simplified...

`for(let i=0,count=0; i < processedData.length && count<100; count+=validateEmail(processedData[i]),i++)`